# postgresl.conf vs conf.d/*: which has greater precedence

Tags: postgresql, configuration

If the same parameter it's set on `./postgresql.conf` and on `./conf.d/something.conf` which one has preference or which one overwrites the other one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where in the `postgresql.conf` you have the corresponding `include_dir` directive; normally it would be at the very end, so any assignment in `conf.d` will override the previously assigned parameter value.

Comment: Is this something for postgresql only or something that usually applies to linux packages?